# IntelliJ Format/colour issues when injecting dependencies to templates in Scala Play 2 Views

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playback, twirl, intellij-2020

In IntelliJ IDE, when I add `@this()` for injecting dependencies, All the colours go crazy and I also start getting error underlies. The code works absolutely fine, but it both looks ugly and prevents me from inspecting things in the code.

I have spent all my afternoon searching for perhaps a missing plugin or an editor setting or something, but I haven't found anything that resolves this issue.

Am I missing a plugin or something? Any help is much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Probably related to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-10653. Doesn't it help to run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: No, tried that, didn't help.

Comment: Please report new issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL. If it's possible please attach sample project for investigation.